# How to access baseUrl method from axios in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I haven't managed to find a solution/satisfying explanation of how to actually get the value of the baseUrl method from Axios.
As you can see my solution was pasting the API directly into the API.get() but I want to get the value of the "baseUrl" method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
//Importing axios from node_modules and assign variable axios
import axios from 'axios';

//Here's my issue, don't know how to access baseUrl string
const api = axios.create({
  baseUrl: `http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees`
})

api.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees').then(res => {
//Getting JSON data from HTTP and put it inside res arrow function.
  let resJSON = res.data.data;
//Assign the res object into a variable for easier access
  //console.log(resJSON);
  let i = 0;
//looping through the length of the object and display each objects
  for (i = 0; i < resJSON.length; i++) {
    console.log(resJSON[i]);
  }
})

//The code below haven't been changed
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[image: Image of fetch actually getting meaningful data]

Comment: The whole point of setting the base URL is that you *don't* need to access it, just use `api.get("/")`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hi Jon, would you mind explain this to me, compare these two solutions
When I called the axios.get('/') my console.log returns the id,employee_salary and employee_age as integer whilst the employee_name is strings which is the way I prefer.

But when I separate the base URL inside the baseURL i.e "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1" and call the axios.get('/employees') the key values of object is all strings? In terms of "best practices" what would be the recommended way to get the JSON objects? key:<all strings> or key:<integer/strings>? Use the attached image above as ref.

Comment: I can't explain it; t seems very unlikely that would make a difference, you're making the same request however you split the path parts between the baseUrl and the argument to the get method. Questions about best practices are usually opinion based thus off topic.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically create a custom instance of `axios` that holds your application options.

### ex:

Create a new file let's say "client.js"

Add an axios instance.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const axiosClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1',
});
```

In your component:

```
import {axiosClient} from './client.js'

....
axiosClient.get('/employees')
```

For more options on how to use `axios.create()` refer to axios' README file on github

https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig